# How do I concatenate a percentage referring to a cell

Tags: excel

I know how to use the concatenate and TEXT feature when referring to a date. But can't figure out how to show a percentage in a concatenate formula referencing to a cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TEXT funtion for this as well

for example

```
=+CONCATENATE(A1,"  ",TEXT(B1,"##%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`="Percentage: " & TEXT(A1,"0.00%")`

[image]